# Using an onclick event to create an iframe overlay

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have an embedded google map on my site that changes location when a button is clicked.

```
<% provide(:title, "Car Pooling") %>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <h1>Car Pooling</h1>

<body>
<button data-long="23.7454209" data-lat="37.9758438" typeof="button">Na Fianna</button>
<button data-long="2.3470599" data-lat="48.8588589" typeof="button">St. Pauls</button>
<button data-long="-122.081267" data-lat="37.4038194" typeof="button">Kevins</button>
<br>
<div id="info">48.8588589,2.3470599</div>
<br>
<iframe id="map" width="600" height="450" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=AIzaSyDxbtgKBohoqXqwPNEYOUGB5WNftHUVDWw&amp;center=48.8588589,2.3470599&amp;zoom=18&amp;maptype=roadmap" frameborder="0" style="border: 0px currentColor; border-image: none;"></iframe>
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
_uacct = "UA-162157-1";
urchinTracker();
</script> 

</body>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $('button').each(function(i, btn) {
    $(btn).click(function() {
      var el = $(this)[0];
      var urlbeg="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/view?key=AIzaSyDxbtgKBohoqXqwPNEYOUGB5WNftHUVDWw&center=";
      var urlend="&zoom=18&maptype=roadmap";
      var lat=el.dataset.lat;
      var lng=el.dataset.long;
      $('#info').text(lat+","+lng);
      $("iframe").attr("src",urlbeg+lat+","+lng+urlend);
    });
  });
});
```

I would like to just display the buttons and then when one is clicked the map is displayed as an overlay in the center of the screen in the foreground with the background faded slightly.

Can anyone advise on how to tackle this? Should it be done using CSS or javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this with JQuery and CSS as follows. With this method you have the flexibility to fine tune the effect to your liking.

CSS:

```
iframe {
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.body-shade {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.5);
}
```

JQuery:

```
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('iframe').fadeIn('slow');
    $('body').toggleClass('body-shade');
  });
```

Keep in mind you can slow down the effect and change it using this method either through the jquery function or via CSS3 transition's.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance JacopG182. It is now not showing a map except when I button is clicked which is great. It is not showing as an overlay though - just as a part of the page. I will also now need to add a close option to the map in order to clear it off the page. Any tips???

Comment: No problem. Not sure what exactly could be causing the issue for you so I have made a codepen with a bare bones example of your code and my suggested css and jquery in that you can see a working example, the Iframe might not be there but the buttons and body shade will work. http://codepen.io/jacobg182/pen/BoXqYG